# Hardhat testing error: Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, testing

I've been testing a covered-call smart contract in hardhat but keep getting this error. Specifically my executeOption function which should enable the call buyer to execute the option at the given strike price.

here is the smartcontract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract CoveredCallContract {

    address public callWriter;
    address public callBuyer;
    uint public amount;
    uint public optionPrice;
    uint public strikePrice;
    uint public expiryDate;
    bool wasPurchased;
    bool optionExecuted;

    constructor(uint _amount, uint _optionPrice, uint _strikePrice) {
        callWriter = msg.sender;
        amount = _amount;
        optionPrice = _optionPrice;
        strikePrice = _strikePrice;
        expiryDate = block.timestamp + 1 weeks;
    }

    function setWasPurchased(bool _wasPurchased) public {
        wasPurchased = _wasPurchased;
    }

    function setOptionExecuted(bool _optionExecuted) public {
        optionExecuted = _optionExecuted;
    }

    // this function is how the callwriter deposits the collateral to cover the option
    function depositCollateral() public payable {
        require(msg.value >= amount, " Insufficient balance");
    }

    // this function allows the buyer to purchase the contract and pay the premium
    function purchaseOption() external payable {
        // ensure buyer hasn't already bought the option
        require(wasPurchased == false);
        // ensure buyer sends the correct amount
        require(msg.value == optionPrice, "Incorrect purchase price");
        // set the option buyer to the callbuyer
        callBuyer = msg.sender;
        // if the buyer buys the option, the price is transfered directly to the writer
        payable(callWriter).transfer(msg.value);
        // set the wasPurchased to true one the option has been purchased
        wasPurchased = true;

    }

    // the option will be executed if the price of ETH is above the strike price 
    function executeOption(address _callBuyer) external payable {
        // ensure the buyer has purchased the option
        require(wasPurchased == true, "Option has not been purchased");
        // ensure the option has not already been executed
        require(optionExecuted == false, "you cannot execute an option twice");
        // make sure it's the buyer executing the contract
        require(msg.sender == _callBuyer, "Unauthorized");
        // ensure the contract has been funded by the call writer
        require(address(this).balance == amount, "Funding error");
        // ensure the amount the buyer pays at execution is equal to the strikeprice
        require(msg.value == strikePrice, "Payment error");
        // make sure the contract has not expired
        require(block.timestamp < expiryDate, "Option has already expired");
        // if all the above hold transfer the amount to the buyer
        payable(_callBuyer).transfer(address(this).balance);
        // set option execution to ture now that the option has been executed
        optionExecuted = true;
    }

    // if the option is not executed the initial funds will be sent back to the call writer
    function refund() public payable {
        // validate the caller of the refund is only the call writer
        require(block.timestamp >= expiryDate, "Option has not expired yet");
        require(wasPurchased == false, "Option has already been purchased");    
        payable(callWriter).transfer((address(this).balance));
    }
}
```

here's the test below. I've included the preceeding tests as well so you can see how it leads up to the executeOption test:

```
const { expect, assert } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const { BigNumber } = require("@ethersproject/bignumber");
const { Web3Provider } = require("@ethersproject/providers");

describe("CoveredCallContract", function () {

  let coveredCallContract;
  let callWriter;
  let callBuyer;
  const amount = ethers.utils.parseEther("1");
  const optionPrice = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.1");
  const strikePrice = ethers.utils.parseEther("1.5");

  this.beforeEach(async () => {
    [callWriter, callBuyer] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const CoveredCallContract = await ethers.getContractFactory("CoveredCallContract");
    coveredCallContract = await CoveredCallContract.deploy(amount, optionPrice, strikePrice);
    await coveredCallContract.deployed();
  });

  it("should have call writer address equal the deployer address", async () => {
    assert(await coveredCallContract.connect(callWriter))
  });

  it('should set option expiry date', async () => {
    const expiryDate = await coveredCallContract.expiryDate();
    assert(expiryDate);
  });

  it('should set wasPurchased bool to false', async () => {
    await coveredCallContract.setWasPurchased(false);
  });

  it('should set optionExecution bool to false', async () => {
    await coveredCallContract.setOptionExecuted(false);
  });

  it('should NOT deposit collateral if writers balance is too low', async () => {
    const writerBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(callWriter.address);
    expect(writerBalance).to.be.greaterThan(amount);
  });
    
  it('should deposit the collateral', async () => {
    await coveredCallContract.connect(callWriter).depositCollateral({value: amount});
    const balance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(coveredCallContract.address);
    const amountHex = ethers.utils.hexlify(amount);
    const balanceHex = ethers.utils.hexlify(balance);
    assert.equal(balanceHex, amountHex);
  });

  it('should NOT buy option if not paying the correct price', async () => {
    await expect(coveredCallContract.purchaseOption({value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.2")})).to.be.revertedWith("Incorrect purchase price");
  });

  it('should purchase option', async () => {
    await coveredCallContract.setWasPurchased(false);
    await coveredCallContract.connect(callBuyer).purchaseOption({value: optionPrice});
  });
  
  it('should execute option', async () => {
    // ensure the option has been purchased
    await coveredCallContract.setWasPurchased(true);
    // ensure the option has not already been executed
    await coveredCallContract.setOptionExecuted(false);
    // ensure the contract has been funded
    await coveredCallContract.connect(callWriter).depositCollateral({value: amount});
    const balance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(coveredCallContract.address);
    assert.equal(balance.toString(), amount.toString());
    // ensure the call buyer is purchasing the option
    await coveredCallContract.connect(callBuyer).purchaseOption({value: optionPrice});
    // ensure the contract has not expired yet
    const expiryDate = await coveredCallContract.expiryDate();
    assert(expiryDate);
    assert.isBelow(
      Number((await hre.network.provider.request({
        method: "evm_blockTimestamp"
      })).result), 
      expiryDate.toNumber()
    );
    // execute the option
    const tx = await coveredCallContract.executeOption({from: callBuyer.address, value: strikePrice});
    // mark the option as executed
    await coveredCallContract.setOptionExecuted(true);
    // check transaction was initiated by the call buyer
    assert.equal(tx.from, callBuyer); 
    // ensure the amount being paid at execution is equal to the strikeprice
    const expectedStrikePrice = strikePrice;
    assert.equal(strikePrice.toString(), expectedStrikePrice.toString());
    // ensure the collateral has been trasferred to the call buyer
    const buyerBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(callBuyer.address);
    assert.equal(buyerBalance.toString(), amount.toString());
  });
```

I'm not quite sure what my error is - so appreciate any feedback.

Comment: without revert string can happen because of a division by 0 , incorrect method signature, non-existent contract address, invalid opcode, and lots of other things. you should add EVM trace if you want some help

Comment: thanks for your feedback - how do I add EVM trace?